# How to add a path multi files and output Folder using python

Tags: python, output, glob

I have multi files json in a folder I want to add a path in my code and output

files_json = ('/myfiles/*.json')
output = /OutputfilesFolder/

```
import json
import re
from googletrans import Translator
from glob import glob

translator = Translator()

def translate_dict(en_dict):
    es_dict = {}
    for key, value in en_dict.items():
        # Identify placeholders
        placeholders = re.findall(r'{.*?}', value)
        
        # Remove placeholders from the original string
        for placeholder in placeholders:
            value = value.replace(placeholder, '')

        # Translate the string without placeholders
        translation = translator.translate(value, dest='ar')
        
        # Add the placeholders back to the translated string
        translated_value = translation.text
        for placeholder in placeholders:
            translated_value += ' ' + placeholder
        
        es_dict[key] = translated_value.strip()
    return es_dict

files_json = {
    "000a1a966f5e5aba0e7c": "Update Settings",
    "00a60ec8ca21b351da90": "Terms Url",
    #...
    # include all the keys and values you want to translate
    #...
}

# Get the Spanish translation
es_dict = translate_dict(files_json)

# Print the Spanish dictionary
print(json.dumps(es_dict, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Using a library glob .I hope to help